# bash script to list duplicate hash files

Tags: bash, hash

I want to create a bash script that searches a given directory for pictures to copy. the pictures have to have the name format IMG_\d\d\d\d.JPG. If the pictures have a duplicate filename, then copy them to /images/archives and append .JPG to the end of their name, so the duplicates have .JPG.JPG. There are also duplicate pictures, so I want to hash each picture and check if it is a duplicate picture. If it is a duplicate picture, then do not copy the duplicate into /archives but store the duplicate file path into a file called output.txt.

I am struggling with trying to get the duplicate hashes to display the filenames as well. This is what I had so far:

```
    if [ -d $1 ]
then echo using directory $1 as source
else echo Sorry, not a valid drive
exit
fi
if [  -d $2 ]
then echo $2 target location already exists
else mkdir -p $2 
fi
cd $1
myList=`find . -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*MG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG"`
echo $myList
ImagesToCopy=`find . -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*MG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG" -exec md5sum {} \; | cut -f1 -d" " | sort | uniq`
echo $ImagesToCopy
```

This gives me a list of the files I need to copy and their hashes. In the command line if I type in the command:

```
# find . -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*MG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG" -exec md5sum {} \; | sort | cut -f1 -d" "| uniq -d
```

I receive the results:

```
266ab54fd8a6dbc7ba61a0ee526763e5
88761da2c2a0e57d8aab5327a1bb82a9
cc640e50f69020dd5d2d4600e20524ac
```

This is the list of duplicate files that I do not want to copy but I want to also display the file path and filenames alongside this, like this:

```
    # find . -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*MG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG" -exec md5sum {} \; | sort -k1 | uniq -u
043007387f39f19b3418fcba67b8efda  ./IMG_1597.JPG
05f0c10c49983f8cde37d65ee5790a9f  ./images/IMG_2012/IMG_2102.JPG
077c22bed5e0d0fba9e666064105dc72  ./DCIM/IMG_0042.JPG
1a2764a21238aaa1e28ea6325cbf00c2  ./images/IMG_2012/IMG_1403.JPG
1e343279cd05e8dbf371331314e3a2f6  ./images/IMG_1959.JPG
2226e652bf5e3ca3fbc63f3ac169c58b  ./images/IMG_0058.JPG
266ab54fd8a6dbc7ba61a0ee526763e5  ./images/IMG_0079.JPG
266ab54fd8a6dbc7ba61a0ee526763e5  ./images/IMG_2012/IMG_0079.JPG
2816dbcff1caf70aecdbeb934897fd6e  ./images/IMG_1233.JPG
451110cc2aff1531e64f441d253b7fec  ./DCIM/103canon/IMG_0039.JPG
45a00293c0837f10e9ec2bfd96edde9f  ./DCIM/103canon/IMG_0097.JPG
486f9dd9ee20ba201f0fd9a23c8e7289  ./images/IMG_2013/IMG_0060.JPG
4c2054c57a2ca71d65f92caf49721b4e  ./DCIM/IMG_1810.JPG
53313e144725be3993b1d208c7064ef6  ./IMG_2288.JPG
5ac56dcddd7e0fd464f9b243213770f5  ./images/IMG_2012/favs/IMG_0039.JPG
65b15ebd20655fae29f0d2cf98588fc3  ./DCIM/IMG_2564.JPG
88761da2c2a0e57d8aab5327a1bb82a9  ./images/IMG_2012/favs/IMG_1729.JPG
88761da2c2a0e57d8aab5327a1bb82a9  ./images/IMG_2013/IMG_1729.JPG
8fc75b0dd2806d5b4b2545aa89618eb6  ./DCIM/103canon/IMG_2317.JPG
971f0a4a064bb1a2517af6c058dc3eb3  ./images/IMG_2012/favs/IMG_2317.JPG
aad617065e46f97d97bd79d72708ec10  ./images/IMG_2013/IMG_1311.JPG
c937509b5deaaee62db0bf137bc77366  ./DCIM/IMG_1152.JPG
cc640e50f69020dd5d2d4600e20524ac  ./images/IMG_2012/favs/IMG_2013.JPG
cc640e50f69020dd5d2d4600e20524ac  ./images/IMG_2013/IMG_2013.JPG
d8edfcc3f9f322ae5193e14b5f645368  ./images/IMG_2012/favs/IMG_1060.JPG
dcc1da7daeb8507f798e4017149356c5  ./DCIM/103canon/IMG_1600.JPG
ded2f32c88796f40f080907d7402eb44  ./IMG_0085.JPG
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you run md5sum, the output is `SUM FILENAME`.  You remove FILENAME.  Why?  Keep it.  Your sort and uniq will still work, and you will have the filename right there, without any additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have the results of `md5sum`.  For example:

```
$ cat file
266ab54fd8a6dbc7ba61a0ee526763e5 /path/to/file1a
88761da2c2a0e57d8aab5327a1bb82a9 /path/to/file2a
266ab54fd8a6dbc7ba61a0ee526763e5 /path/to/file1b
cc640e50f69020dd5d2d4600e20524ac /path/to/file3
88761da2c2a0e57d8aab5327a1bb82a9 /path/to/file2b
```

To remove duplicates from the list, use awk:

```
$ awk '!($1 in a){a[$1]; print}' file
266ab54fd8a6dbc7ba61a0ee526763e5 /path/to/file1a
88761da2c2a0e57d8aab5327a1bb82a9 /path/to/file2a
cc640e50f69020dd5d2d4600e20524ac /path/to/file3
```

This uses the array `a` to keep track of which md5 sums we have seen so far.  For each line, if the md5 has not appeared before,  `!($1 in a)`, we mark that md5 as having been seen and print the line.

#### Alternative

A shorter version of the code is:

```
$ awk '!a[$1]++' file
266ab54fd8a6dbc7ba61a0ee526763e5 /path/to/file1a
88761da2c2a0e57d8aab5327a1bb82a9 /path/to/file2a
cc640e50f69020dd5d2d4600e20524ac /path/to/file3
```

This uses array `a` to count the number of times that md5sum `$1` has appeared.  If the count is initially zero, then the line is printed.